# How to remove a row a specific row with null value

Tags: python, pandas

This is a subset of data frame that I have. For each row that sentence column has value, column A B C D are repeated for the next two rows without having a value for the sentence column. How can I  remove the second row with null value for sentences. I need to keep the first row with null value for sentence column.

```
     A    B   C    D             R      sentence              ADR 
    112 135 21  EffexorXR.21    1    lack of good feeling.    good
    113 135 21  EffexorXR.21    1                               1 
    114 135 21  EffexorXR.21    1   
    115 136 21  EffexorXR.21    2   Feel disconnected         disconnected
    116 136 21  EffexorXR.21    2        
    117 136 21  EffexorXR.21    2    
    118 142 22  EffexorXR.22    1   Weight gain                gain
    119 142 22  EffexorXR.22    1                                1
    120 142 22  EffexorXR.22    1
```

The output is like this

```
   A    B   C    D             R        sentence               ADR     
    112 135 21  EffexorXR.21    1    lack of good feeling.     good
    113 135 21  EffexorXR.21    1                               1
    115 136 21  EffexorXR.21    2    Feel disconnected        disconnected       
    116 136 21  EffexorXR.21    2   
    118 142 22  EffexorXR.22    1    Weight gain               gain
    119 142 22  EffexorXR.22    1                               1
```

If I use the following code:

`df = df[pd.notnull(df['sentences'])]`, Then It will remove both rows with null values. Any suggestion ?

The following solution does not work.

```
df.set_index('A').drop_duplicates().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can see duplicates of combined columns and use it to `mask` original `dataframe`:

```
new_df = df[~df[['B','C','D', 'R', 'sentence']].duplicated()]
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
     A    B   C             D  R               sentence           ADR
0  112  135  21  EffexorXR.21  1  lack of good feeling.          good
1  113  135  21  EffexorXR.21  1                                    1
3  115  136  21  EffexorXR.21  2      Feel disconnected  disconnected
4  116  136  21  EffexorXR.21  2                                     
6  118  142  22  EffexorXR.22  1            Weight gain          gain
7  119  142  22  EffexorXR.22  1                                    1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use drop_duplicates. Column A is unique so we set it as index. It will use the remaining columns to check for duplicates and drop them if any. Finally reset_index to bring column A back.

```
df.set_index('A').drop_duplicates().reset_index()
Out[847]: 
     A    B   C             D  R               sentence
0  112  135  21  EffexorXR.21  1  lack of good feeling.
1  113  135  21  EffexorXR.21  1                       
2  115  136  21  EffexorXR.21  2      Feel disconnected
3  116  136  21  EffexorXR.21  2                       
4  118  142  22  EffexorXR.22  1            Weight gain
5  119  142  22  EffexorXR.22  1
```

Updated answer to use only a subset as keys for checking duplicates.

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['B','C','D','sentence'])
Out[866]: 
     A    B   C             D  R               sentence           ADR
0  112  135  21  EffexorXR.21  1  lack of good feeling.          good
1  113  135  21  EffexorXR.21  1                                    1
3  115  136  21  EffexorXR.21  2      Feel disconnected  disconnected
4  116  136  21  EffexorXR.21  2                                  nan
6  118  142  22  EffexorXR.22  1            Weight gain          gain
7  119  142  22  EffexorXR.22  1                                    1
```

Comment: thanks, But I can not use duplicate. Because there are other columns having values for the first row with null value in sentence column. In addition, for the second row, other column may have some values. Do you have any suggestion if the two rows are not duplicated ?

Comment: @Mary, I've updated answer based on your update. If column D can be used to uniquely identify the groups, you can just use ['D','sentence'] as keys.