# How to select columns of a data frame not in a list of names in Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I want to subset the column index of a data frame, by keeping all of the columns that do NOT start with a certain string. Right now I can filter the column index for columns that start with a certain string, but I'd like to do the opposite and exclude column names that match a certain criterion.

If trying to keep the columns

If trying to keep column names that start with FR, I use this code, which works.

```
factor_list = df2.filter(like = 'FR_', axis=1).columns
```

Trying to exclude columns that start with "FR", I've tried many things including the following:

```
factor_list = df2.filter(like != 'FR_', axis=1).columns
factor_list = ~df2.filter(like = 'FR_', axis=1).columns
```

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071199/drop-columns-whose-name-contains-a-specific-string-from-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were quite close with `df.filter`. In this case it's easier to use a regular expression by filtering all the columns which don't start (`?!^`) with `FR_`:

```
df.filter(regex='^(?!FR_)')

   Col1  Col3
0     2     8
1     0     7
2     4     1
3     2     6
4     4     8
```

```
# Example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':np.random.randint(0,10,5),
                   'FR_Col2':np.random.randint(0,10,5),
                   'Col3':np.random.randint(0,10,5),
                   'FR_Col4':np.random.randint(0,10,5)})

   Col1  FR_Col2  Col3  FR_Col4
0     2        1     8        5
1     0        7     7        9
2     4        8     1        9
3     2        2     6        9
4     4        9     8        3
```

Comment: Thank you for the additional context and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. Please check the above link for more details.

```
factor_list = df2.loc[:,~df.columns.str.startswith('FR')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```py
factor_list = df2.filter(regex = '^(?!FR_).*', axis=1).columns
```

Comment: This works because I can just add the code directly into my program.