# drop rows with specific string in it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
    difer        
0   0.11, word;; 12          
1   NaN          
2   01_00532      
3   NaN           
4   0.11, word;; 13443           
5   0.10          
6   Nan
```

I want to drop the entery column if it contains a specific string , in this case 'word'

[i found this answer but didnt know ho to apply it correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44272830/12267139)

Comment: Not sure if understand, it means there is more columns and is necessary remove `difer` column if `word`? Can you add expected output?

Comment: `df[~df['difer'].str.contains("word")]`

Comment: it sould deleate these rows `0.11, word;; 13443  `, `0   0.11, word;; 12  `