# Dropping a row in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

Why wont this code drop a row based on the column value

```
dete_date = dete_data[dete_data.dete_start_date != 'Not Stated']
```

the rows with 'Not stated' in the dete_start_date column still exist after running code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting DataFrame row in Pandas based on column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172851/deleting-dataframe-row-in-pandas-based-on-column-value)

Comment: ```dete_date = dete_data.loc[dete_data.dete_start_date != 'Not Stated']``` but are you sure 'Not stated' is exactly the way it's phrased (without extra spaces, case sensitive etc)

Comment: 'Not stated' or 'Not Stated' ?

Comment: using .loc worked

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071199/drop-columns-whose-name-contains-a-specific-string-from-pandas-dataframe