# Extract maximum value from columns having similar names

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to ask how I can select the highest values per each rows within the following columns

```
 ID   mean_idx269   mean_idx270 mean_idx271 mean_idx272 mean_idx273 mean_idx274 mean_idx275 ... 

 1      37          42          44           40          42          35         46      
 2      50          41          23           64          21          64         21
 3      12          42          55           10          22          12         22
```

My expected output would be:

```
 ID   mean_idx269   mean_idx270 mean_idx271 mean_idx272 mean_idx273 mean_idx274 mean_idx275 ... max

 1      37          42          44           40          42          35         46           46   
 2      50          41          23           64          21          64         21           64
 3      12          42          55           10          22          12         22           55
```

**There are other columns in the dataframe**, named in a different way, but **I would need to extract the maximum from those columns starting/containing `mean_idx`**.

The result should be a dataframe containing the `ID` column and the columns containing `mean_idx`.

I do not know if `max()` function can be used in this case, as I need to select through more columns per each ID.

Comment: You can use `df.append(df[list_with_filtered_colnames]).max(axis=1), axis=1)`

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19071572/6692898) on how to filter columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Use a list comprehension to get the desired columns with matching words
- Create a separate dataframe containing only the desired columns

  - Add the `'ID'` column to the front, because it won't match the list comprehension.
- Use the [`.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) method and specify `axis=1` for row wise.

  - `df_subset[mean_cols].max(axis=1)` and not just `df_subset.max(axis=1)`, otherwise `ID` will also be used to determine `max`.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID': [1, 2, 3],
        'mean_idx269': [37, 50, 12],
        'mean_idx270': [42, 41, 42],
        'mean_idx271': [44, 23, 55],
        'mean_idx272': [40, 64, 10],
        'mean_idx273': [42, 21, 22],
        'mean_idx274': [35, 64, 12],
        'mean_idx275': [46, 21, 22],
        'test_idx333': [1, 3, 4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# get the columns with the desired pattern
mean_cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'mean_idx' in col]

# create a subset of the dataframe with the desired columns
df_subset = df[['ID'] + mean_cols].copy()

# get max for specific cols
df_subset['max_row'] = df_subset[mean_cols].max(axis=1)

# display(df_subset)
   ID  mean_idx269  mean_idx270  mean_idx271  mean_idx272  mean_idx273  mean_idx274  mean_idx275  max_row
0   1           37           42           44           40           42           35           46       46
1   2           50           41           23           64           21           64           21       64
2   3           12           42           55           10           22           12           22       55
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`pd.DataFrame.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to select only columns that match a pattern:

```
df['max'] = df.filter(like='mean_idx').max(axis=1)
```

Ouput:

```
   ID  mean_idx269  mean_idx270  mean_idx271  mean_idx272  mean_idx273  mean_idx274  mean_idx275  max
0   1           37           42           44           40           42           35           46   46
1   2           50           41           23           64           21           64           21   64
2   3           12           42           55           10           22           12           22   55
```