# Delete specific strings from pandas dataframe with operators chaining

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, operators, regular-language

I want to delete specific strings with regular expressions from the column `Sorte` which I don't want to have in my dataframe `file_df` with the following code:

```
file_df = file_df[(file_df.Sorte != 'sonstige') & (file_df.Sorte != 'verauslagte Portokosten')
                  & (file_df.Sorte != 'erhaltenenzahlung Re  vom')
                  & (file_df.Sorte != 'geleistetenzahlung aus Re-Nr')
                  & (file_df.Sorte != '^.*Holzkisten geliefert.*$')
                  & (file_df.Sorte != '^.*Infomaterialktionspakete.*$')
                  & (file_df.Sorte != '^.*Aloe Vera  haben wir nicht im Sortiment.*$') 
                  & (file_df.Sorte != '^.*Anzeigenvorlage Planten ut`norden.*$')]
```

But somehow when I execute this code these strings still are in the dataset and I can not figure out why. I wanted to chain this expression to not create so many copies.

**Update**

The code worked for some strings in the dataset, for others not.

Comment: You are **not** using regular expressions here, but simple string comparison

Comment: Should you be using OR '|' instead ?  You code seems to be saying Var != 'A' & Var != 'B'.  Can't be A and B at the same time.

Comment: @mozway How can I compare strings using regular expressions?

Comment: @EBDS As all the strings are in the column "Sorte", I guess that "&" should work as the condition that all the unwanted strings shouldn't be in the remaining dataset can be fulfilled, but I can try "|"

Comment: I think could try ==   and "|" since you want to remove them. Then use ~ to negate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out another solution that worked out for me derived from the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54410702/14553595, which is basically a combination of your suggestions in the comments:

```
file_df = file_df.loc[:,~(file_df.columns.str.contains('^.*Fracht.*$', case=False)
                          | file_df.columns.str.contains('^.*Angebotspaket.*$', case=False)
                          | file_df.columns.str.contains('^.*Werbe.*$', case=False)
                          | file_df.columns.str.contains('^.*Vita.Verde.*$', case=False)
                          | file_df.columns.str.contains('^.*zahlung.*$', case=False)
                          | file_df.columns.str.contains('^.*Europalette.*$', case=False)
                          | file_df.columns.str.contains('^.*Angebotspaket.*$', case=False)
                          | file_df.columns.str.contains('^.*Aufkleber fuer Saeule.*$', case=False)
                          | file_df.columns.str.contains('^.*Aufsetzer.*$', case=False)
                          | file_df.columns.str.contains('^.*Ausstellen der Pflanzen in die Beete  pauschal.*$', case=False)
                          | file_df.columns.str.contains('^.*Ausstellungsflaeche.*$', case=False)
                          | file_df.columns.str.contains('^.*Auswaschen.*$', case=False)
                          | file_df.columns.str.contains('^.*Bild.*$', case=False)
                          | file_df.columns.str.contains('^.*etikette.*$', case=False)
                          )]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
ls = ['sonstige', 'verauslagte Portokosten', 'erhaltenenzahlung Re  vom', ...]
file_df = file_df[~ file_df.country.str.contains('|'.join(ls))]
```